# Remove first 3 characters and last 1 character from all mp3 files in all subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash

In base directory i have folders like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
10
110
```

so in each of them i  have files like

```
  0010011.mp3  0010031.mp3  0010051.mp3  0010071.mp3  0010021.mp3  0010041.mp3  0010061.mp3
```

so i want to remove first 3 characters and last 1 character  so files will look like this

```
 001.mp3   003.mp3   005.mp3   007.mp3   002.mp3   004.mp3  006.mp3
```

i tried this

```
for file in ??????*; do echo mv $file `echo $file | cut -c4-`; done
```

also this is not working in subdirectories it is just if files are in base directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this while loop:

```
cd /base/dir

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   echo mv "$file" "$(sed -E 's~(.*/).{3}(.+).\.~\1\2.~' <<< "$file")"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Once you're satisfied with the results, remove `echo` before `mv` command.

Comment: mv ./36/0360331.mp3 ./033.mp3
mv ./4/0041091.mp3 ./09.mp3

it should be  
mv ./4/0041091.mp3 ./009.mp3

Comment: if folder name is with 1 character it rename to mv ./8/0080351.mp3 ./35.mp3     if folder name is with 2 characters it rename to   mv ./88/0080351.mp3 ./035.mp3    . it should remove 3 characters from filename  (not including directory )

Comment: Is the syntax in this answer superior to `for i in $(find . -type f -print0); do echo mv $i [etc]; done` in some way?

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames all have the same pattern you can cut the characters this way:

```
$ file='0010031.mp3'
$ cut -c4-6,8- <<< "$file"
003.mp3
```

Comment: i need to run in base directory but to apply for each subdirectory

Comment: Just use `basename` + `dirname`.